# Schengen visa permit

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, singaporean-citizens

I am a student with a Singapore passport currently studying in the Czech Republic for a semester. My permit is valid until 2nd of February, I plan to fly to the UK to travel for 3 days before heading back to Singapore from there.

Would there be any problems, such as exit immigration from the Czech Republic to the UK? I searched online that the UK is not part of Schengen Area Agreement states, and my passport has a visa free entry to the UK.

Comment: edit: i leaving Czech Republic on 2nd feb(last day of my visa permit) not sure if this will affect any procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to leave the Schengen area so there should be no problem leaving Czech Republic. You also should have no problem visiting the UK: the border officer just needs to be satisfied that you can afford your visit, have a genuine visitor purpose such as tourism, and won't overstay. You will be able to show your onward ticket to SG, bank statement or other funds, and some paperwork from your university showing that you need to go to Singapore to complete your course. Nobody on the internet can guarantee you will be able to enter the UK, but it seems to me that your circumstances are those of a genuine visitor.

Comment: i planning to leave Czech Republic on the exact day of 2nd Feb. Not sure if this will affect any thing during immigration.